# How can I configure Cache then network with SW Precache?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, sw-precache

I have only found two options that accept this plugin that are cacheFirst and networkFirst but I can not find the option for Cache then network to get updates.

```
    { 
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/mlm-s2-p\.mlstatic\.com/,
      handler: 'cacheFirst',
    options: {
        cache: {
            maxEntries: 1000,
            name: 'mercadolibre-images-cache-s2c'
          }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation for [Caching Files with Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker#top_of_page)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Of course, but the plugin I am working with does not have to write the entire code of the caching form. Did you read and check the plugin I'm using? https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache

Answer (score 0):

`handler: 'fastest'` will give you the behavior that you want. That corresponds to the `fastest` handler in `sw-toolbox`: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/sw-toolbox/api.html#toolboxfastest